# @requestbody cannot get properties name capitalizations in java spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, request, controller

My problem is when creating properties of an object.
Attribute names are capitalized (Required for my problem)
When I send a JSON request using postman with keys capitalized @RequestBody can't read those keys.
And one more thing the body that I return has properties that are not capitalized as I would like.
I know this problem lies in getter and setter but don't know how to solve it

Here is my code

```java
package com.truong.demo.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * The persistent class for the VTP_HTDV database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "VTP_HTDV")
@NamedQuery(name = "VtpHtdv.findAll", query = "SELECT v FROM VtpHtdv v")
public class VtpHtdv implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "HOOK_VTP_HTDV_SEQ", sequenceName = "HOOK_VTP_HTDV_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "HOOK_VTP_HTDV_SEQ")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "ORDER_NUMBER")
    private String ORDER_NUMBER;

    @Column(name = "ORDER_REFERENCE")
    private String ORDER_REFERENCE;

    @Column(name = "ORDER_STATUSDATE")
    private String ORDER_STATUSDATE;

    @Column(name = "ORDER_STATUS")
    private long ORDER_STATUS;

    @Column(name = "STATUS_NAME")
    private String STATUS_NAME;

    @Column(name = "LOCALION_CURRENTLY")
    private String LOCALION_CURRENTLY;

    @Column(name = "NOTE")
    private String NOTE;

    @Column(name = "MONEY_COLLECTION")
    private long MONEY_COLLECTION;

    @Column(name = "MONEY_FEECOD")
    private long MONEY_FEECOD;

    @Column(name = "MONEY_TOTAL")
    private long MONEY_TOTAL;

    @Column(name = "EXPECTED_DELIVERY")
    private String EXPECTED_DELIVERY;

    @Column(name = "PRODUCT_WEIGHT")
    private long PRODUCT_WEIGHT;

    @Column(name = "ORDER_SERVICE")
    private String ORDER_SERVICE;

    public String getORDER_NUMBER() {
        return ORDER_NUMBER;
    }

    public void setORDER_NUMBER(String oRDER_NUMBER) {
        ORDER_NUMBER = oRDER_NUMBER;
    }

    public String getORDER_REFERENCE() {
        return ORDER_REFERENCE;
    }

    public void setORDER_REFERENCE(String oRDER_REFERENCE) {
        ORDER_REFERENCE = oRDER_REFERENCE;
    }

    public String getORDER_STATUSDATE() {
        return ORDER_STATUSDATE;
    }

    public void setORDER_STATUSDATE(String oRDER_STATUSDATE) {
        ORDER_STATUSDATE = oRDER_STATUSDATE;
    }

    public long getORDER_STATUS() {
        return ORDER_STATUS;
    }

    public void setORDER_STATUS(long oRDER_STATUS) {
        ORDER_STATUS = oRDER_STATUS;
    }

    public String getSTATUS_NAME() {
        return STATUS_NAME;
    }

    public void setSTATUS_NAME(String sTATUS_NAME) {
        STATUS_NAME = sTATUS_NAME;
    }

    public String getLOCALION_CURRENTLY() {
        return LOCALION_CURRENTLY;
    }

    public void setLOCALION_CURRENTLY(String lOCALION_CURRENTLY) {
        LOCALION_CURRENTLY = lOCALION_CURRENTLY;
    }

    public String getNOTE() {
        return NOTE;
    }

    public void setNOTE(String nOTE) {
        NOTE = nOTE;
    }

    public long getMONEY_COLLECTION() {
        return MONEY_COLLECTION;
    }

    public void setMONEY_COLLECTION(long mONEY_COLLECTION) {
        MONEY_COLLECTION = mONEY_COLLECTION;
    }

    public long getMONEY_FEECOD() {
        return MONEY_FEECOD;
    }

    public void setMONEY_FEECOD(long mONEY_FEECOD) {
        MONEY_FEECOD = mONEY_FEECOD;
    }

    public long getMONEY_TOTAL() {
        return MONEY_TOTAL;
    }

    public void setMONEY_TOTAL(long mONEY_TOTAL) {
        MONEY_TOTAL = mONEY_TOTAL;
    }

    public String getEXPECTED_DELIVERY() {
        return EXPECTED_DELIVERY;
    }

    public void setEXPECTED_DELIVERY(String eXPECTED_DELIVERY) {
        EXPECTED_DELIVERY = eXPECTED_DELIVERY;
    }

    public long getPRODUCT_WEIGHT() {
        return PRODUCT_WEIGHT;
    }

    public void setPRODUCT_WEIGHT(long pRODUCT_WEIGHT) {
        PRODUCT_WEIGHT = pRODUCT_WEIGHT;
    }

    public String getORDER_SERVICE() {
        return ORDER_SERVICE;
    }

    public void setORDER_SERVICE(String oRDER_SERVICE) {
        ORDER_SERVICE = oRDER_SERVICE;
    }

    public VtpHtdv() {
    }
}
```

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class VTPostHTDVController {
    
    @Autowired
    VtpHtdvService vtpHtdvService;

    Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(VTPostHTDVController.class);

    @PostMapping(value = { "", "/" })
    public ResponseEntity<CliResponse> vanDon(@RequestBody VtpHtdv vtpHtdv) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        CliResponse cliResponse = new CliResponse(Constants.DEFAULT_CODE, Constants.DEFAULT_DESC);

        System.err.println(vtpHtdv.getORDER_NUMBER());// Data print is null
        cliResponse.setData(vtpHtdv);
        

        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(cliResponse);
    }

}
```

This is what I posted

```
{
    "ORDER_NUMBER":"10345381626",
    "ORDER_REFERENCE":"TKS1801492",
    "ORDER_STATUSDATE":"13/12/2018 17:34:05",
    "ORDER_STATUS":200,
    "STATUS_NAME":"TEST - TEST ",
    "LOCALION_CURRENTLY":"TEST ",
    "NOTE":"TEST note",
    "MONEY_COLLECTION":1500000,
    "MONEY_FEECOD":0,
    "MONEY_TOTAL":45650,
    "EXPECTED_DELIVERY":"TEST 2 days",
    "PRODUCT_WEIGHT":245,
    "ORDER_SERVICE":"SCOD"
  }
```

This is the result that I return

```
{
    "statusCode": "200",
    "statusDesc": "OK",
    "data": {
        "expected_DELIVERY": null,
        "money_COLLECTION": 0,
        "order_STATUSDATE": null,
        "money_FEECOD": 0,
        "order_STATUS": 0,
        "note": null,
        "order_REFERENCE": null,
        "money_TOTAL": 0,
        "order_SERVICE": null,
        "order_NUMBER": null,
        "product_WEIGHT": 0,
        "localion_CURRENTLY": null,
        "status_NAME": null
    }
}
```

I tried changing the object's properties from private to public and they worked. But it seems that the properties should not be set to public, right?

As you can see, half of the attribute is returned in lowercase, half in uppercase for example: order_STATUSDATE and I want ORDER_STATUSDATE

Result I want

```
{
  "statusCode": "200",
  "statusDesc": "OK",
  "data": {
    "ORDER_NUMBER": "10345381626",
    "ORDER_REFERENCE": "TKS1801492",
    "ORDER_STATUSDATE": "13/12/2018 17:34:05",
    "ORDER_STATUS": 200,
    "STATUS_NAME": "TEST - TEST ",
    "LOCALION_CURRENTLY": "TEST ",
    "NOTE": "TEST note",
    "MONEY_COLLECTION": 1500000,
    "MONEY_FEECOD": 0,
    "MONEY_TOTAL": 45650,
    "EXPECTED_DELIVERY": "TEST 2 days",
    "PRODUCT_WEIGHT": 245,
    "ORDER_SERVICE": "SCOD"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share CliResponse class

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and I think it's related to this: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/2327

It has something to do with jackson deserialization, you can find more info here: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial#2-creating-custom-serializer-or-deserializer

I solved it by creating a custom mapper that enables the MapperFeature.USE_STD_BEAN_NAMING feature, something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MapperConfig {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper().setPropertyNamingStrategy(propertyNamingStrategy()).enable(MapperFeature.USE_STD_BEAN_NAMING);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you find a solution ;)